# Google maps markers form select-list (using: event.addDomListener & API V3)

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, onchange, event-listener

I’m trying to use a simple dropdown/select-list as a controller for markers (idea is that map would show the selected location/marker). DomListener can handle the onchange-event, but for some reason the marker don’t show up. Do I need to use another event listener, or create the markers some other way?

```
    var map = null;

function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5 ... etc };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);
...

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('SelectList'), 
            'change', function() {

var mypos = document.getElementById('SelectList').value;




alert(mypos); /* output/value is correct */


/* This code doesn’t display marker */
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mypos, 
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });



     });

...
}
------------------------
My HTML select-list:
<select id="SelectList">
<option value="12.123456, 12.987654">location 1</option>
<option value="11.123456, 12.987654">Location 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the "map" variable? Do you get any javascript errors?

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a marker with a comma separated string for the position. It needs to be a LatLng object. Try something like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(mypos.split(',')[0], mypos.split(',')[1]),
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```